# convert dynamic object to C# object

Tags: c#, dynamic

I’m looking to take a dynamic object from a third party API & convert to my C# object with minimal code. 
Sort of like what Dapper does with a SQL statement results to a C# object. Is there a library that would do this? 
I can do it manually like below, but it seems like alot of code to write everytime I want to retrieve from this API.

```
 public IEnumerable<Requirement> Get()
    {
        dynamic requirementsSelect;
        requirementsSelect = _RequirementsRepository.GetRequirements();
        IList<Requirement> Requirements = new List<Requirement>();
        foreach (var req in requirementsSelect)
        {
            Requirement requirement = new Requirement();
            requirement.Text = req.Text;
            requirement.Number = req.Number;
            Requirements.Add(requirement);
            foreach (var node in req.Phrases)
            {
                Requirement reqNode = new Requirement();
                reqNode.Text = node.Text;
                reqNode.Number = node.Number;
                requirement.Nodes.Add(reqNode);
        }
        return Requirements;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: @MokhtarAshour I was thinking of Newtonsoft.Json but I want it to be a c#  object - not json. thanks

Comment: @gypsyCoder sure, but I meant to send the JSON from the 3rd party API and deserialise it to a c# object you have in your code

Comment: @MokhtarAshour thank you. I will look into that now

Comment: @MokhtarAshour When I convert it to JSON -  only one property is coming up. How can I specify what properties should be part of this dynamic object. I convert like this - string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requirements); and it's coming up like this in my browser- [{\"$id\":\"1\"},{\"$id\":\"2\"},{\"$id\":\"3\"}. Thanks

Comment: by default serialization is done to all properties (I assume it's .NET here). BTW what's $id ?

Comment: I don't know why it's coming out like that $id - must be something in the way they coded their objects. I will talk to them and update this post. Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: @MokhtarAshour I communicated with them and they said JSON method is expecting an object that can be serialized into name/value pairs, but their collection doesn't fit that mold. They said I need to serialize a collection and its individual items. Is there a different JSON method I need to use for that? Thank you!

Comment: @shw It's the same method, JsonConvert.SerializeObject() but you'll need to concretely define the objects and use a dictionary<name, value> and value will be the object you are sending.

Comment: @MokhtarAshour I serialized by defining it as  IEnumerable<dynamic> requirements and then specified the properties I needed JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new   { PropertyINeed1 = requirements.Select(x => x.Text),  });. It's working great! If you put in the comment as an answer I will mark it as the answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: @shw Glad I could help. Actually you found the answer yourself, if you write a detailed answer to your own question, I'll upvote it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up returning the third party as JSON as follows. In my specific case the JSON wasn't showing the properties. I resolved by changing the dynamic object to IEnumerable and I was then able to specify which properties I wanted to retrieve using .Select.

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> requirements = _RequirementsRepository.GetRequirements();
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
        {
            Requirement = requirements.Select(x => x.Text),
            Number = requirements.Select(x => x.Number),
        });
```

Thanks!